# why jquery for modifying style properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stylesheet

when it comes to modifying formatting and layouts (style sheets) why would jquery be more advantageous compared to plain javascript??

plain javascript already provides functions like "getelementsbyclassname" or "getelementsbyid" to get a handle for element objects, then why use the jquery interface?

i've read it's "easier"... exactly how?

"more efficient"? but it adds another layer of abstraction...

sure the library is quite easy to download the library since it's CDN-ed, but i want something that's even more minimalistic.

#### EDIT (after hearing ohcibi's response):

ANOTHER QUESTION: if i'm only concerned about modifying style sheets, would sizzle.js be a more minimalistic option? is it's implementation (as far as it's scope go) as complete as jQuery? does it execute faster?

Comment: To answer your last question, pretty much getting computed styles in a cross browser manner.

Comment: Also, I suggest you try to make your question more focused. "Why jquery" would be considered "not constructive" by this site's standards.

Comment: wow, bfavaretto you answered really fast. didn't think anybody would, so i heavily edited the question. anyways i'm asking the same thing.

Comment: "pretty much getting computed styles in a cross browser manner" does that mean that "getelementsbyclassname" or "getelementsbyid", etc, etc are not in the standard library of JS?

Comment: They are standard, I was talking about styles only (you edited that "last sentence" out). By computed styles I mean styles you set via CSS, not element.style. E.g., try to set a div's color with CSS, then read via div.style; it will be blank, you have to check the computed style instead.

Comment: i see... so you're saying that the only thing that JS can modify are element.style's which is an HTML attribute and not set through CSS. ok, got it. still CSS's has been out well over a decade, you'd think JS's standard library would have specific bindings to it.

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. There's nothing jQuery does that you can't do with plain js. jQuery just takes care of browser incompatibilities that you would have to keep in mind, and adds some syntactic sugar.

Comment: ok, so different browsers have different JS extensions to get handles on style properties, jQuery just abstracts all that. still, a standard binding to JS should've been introduced long ago.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply: Cross-browser compatibility, ease of writing/reading, more efficient coding, ubiquitous use.

Also, it doesn't replace ALL javascript. You can use javascript with it if you like or for some simple things that are recognized (more or less) universally by browsers.

Just to restate: more efficient coding.

It's not more minimalistic to write everything in plain js for all the different browser quirks that jquery does for you already. But feel free to do so if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassname` and so on do not provide full CSS3 featured selectors. Plus they are not 100% browser compatible.

If youre only interested into these selectors. Try [sizzle.js](http://sizzlejs.com), its what jQuery uses for the selection of elements.

Comment: i see... thnx for clarifying that... i didn't bother look up whether getElementsByClassname and all those other functions are indeed part of the JS standard library. just easier for me nowadays to ask the question straight up rather than going through piles of documentation...

Comment: ANOTHER QUESTION: if i'm only concerned about modifying style sheets, would sizzle.js be a more minimalistic option? is it's implementation (as far as it's scope go) as complete as jQuery? does it execute faster?

Comment: Concerning the implementation of the selectors its of course as complete as jQuery as jQuery _is using sizzle_ (i.e. when you select an element with jQuery you're selecting it with sizzle).